# ISERROR + VLOOKUP different results for empty cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was trying to make simple check of vlookup:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2;SA!C:K;2;FALSE));"Error";VLOOKUP(B2;SA!C:K;2;FALSE))
```

Issue is that i got two different results for two empty cells.

```
Error
```

and

```
0
```

All cells are with the same type: General. Do not see why this is different :/

I was expecting message in case of iserror = TRUE (cell is empty). This case "Error".

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzoq9530qxtig38/ZZZ.xlsm?dl=0.

Comment: Best would be to include some sample data with expected results

Comment: Screen or file?

Comment: A sample file would be great, but for future reference I think you should include some markdown sample data, for example through [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) tool. Include returned and expected value too

Comment: Added sample file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C2 use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(INDEX(SA!$D:$K,MATCH($B2,SA!$C:$C,0),COLUMN(A1)))=0,"error",INDEX(SA!$D:$K,MATCH($B2,SA!$C:$C,0),COLUMN(A1))),"error")
```

Edit, since you don't really want to show "error" but "" instead, you could also try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SA!$D:$K,MATCH($B2,SA!$C:$C,0),COLUMN(A1))&""),"error")
```

Comment: Only one question. Is it INDEX more advance than VLOOKUP? I thinking if will slow down excel more than vlookup?

Comment: `Index` + `Match` is always at least as fast as `Vlookup` and at best significantly faster! Tip, get into the habit of using this combination instead of the slower `Lookup` functions. Have a read about it [here](https://trumpexcel.com/vlookup-vs-index-match/)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `0` because `VLOOKUP` found key, however the value next to it was empty.

To mark those as `Error` as well use:

```
=IF(LEN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2;SA!C:K;2;FALSE);"Error"))=0;"Error";IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2;SA!C:K;2;FALSE);"Error"))
```

Comment: would suggest to revise your formula as: `= IFERROR(
IF( LEN( VLOOKUP( B2; SA!C:K; 2; FALSE ) ) = 0; "Error",
VLOOKUP( B2; SA!C:K; 2; FALSE ) ); "Error" )`

Comment: Thx. Both are working fine: `=IF(LEN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2;SA!C:K;4;FALSE);"Error"))=0;"Error";IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2;SA!C:K;4;FALSE);"Error"))` and `= IFERROR(IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(B2; SA!C:K;4;FALSE))=0;"Error";VLOOKUP(B2;SA!C:K;4;FALSE));"Error")`. For second I just did correction of typo. I only replace `"Error"` with `""` so vlookup do not return 0 for empty cells. This was my original idea.